# Jenkins declarative pipeline with repo

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, repo

I'm using Jenkins with [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) and I need to create a job triggered by any modification on a [repo](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-repo/) repository and all dependent projects inside the manifest.

Actually I've to do the following fetch and trigger all my dependencies:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('fetch') {
      steps {
        sh 'repo init -u ${MY_REPO_URL}'
        sh 'repo sync'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In a Freestyle project with [repo plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/repo), I only need to add:

[image]

But there is no "Source Code Management" in a pipeline job

What can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what I wasn't understanding is that pollSCM autodetect repo project. So with scheduled trigger, all repositories are checked.

Also, with the pipeline syntax generator I've found this pretty way for init and sync my repository:

```
    checkout changelog: true, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'RepoScm', currentBranch: true, \
        forceSync: true, jobs: 4, manifestBranch: manifestRev, \
        manifestRepositoryUrl: manifestRepo, \
        quiet: false, resetFirst: fullClean, resetFirst: fullReset]
```